# Query for SQL instances returning no results

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to build a query in which I can inventory SQL instances in my environment. I think I might have something slightly off in my code.  When I execute the query, it comes back in seconds with no results. Any help would be appreciated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name0                        AS [Server Name],
                os.caption0                    AS [Operating System],
                cpu.name0                      AS [Chipset],
                c.model0                       AS [Hardware or Platform],
                Count(cpu.resourceid)          AS [Number of CPUs],
                cpu.numberofcores0             AS [Number of Cores per CPU],
                cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors0 AS [Logical Processor Count]
FROM   v_gs_computer_system c
       FULL OUTER JOIN v_r_system s
                    ON s.resourceid = c.resourceid
       FULL OUTER JOIN v_gs_operating_system os
                    ON c.resourceid = os.resourceid
       FULL OUTER JOIN v_gs_processor cpu
                    ON c.resourceid = cpu.resourceid
       FULL OUTER JOIN v_gs_installed_software gis1
                    ON gis1.resourceid = cpu.resourceid
WHERE  s.active0 = 1
       AND s.client0 = 1
       AND s.distinguished_name0 LIKE '%server%'
       AND gis1.publisher0 LIKE '%microsoft%'
       AND gis1.productname0 LIKE '%sql server%'
       AND gis1.installsource0 LIKE '%standard%'
       AND gis1.installsource0 LIKE '%Enterprise%'
GROUP  BY s.name0,
          os.caption0,
          cpu.name0,
          c.model0,
          cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors0,
          cpu.numberofcores0
```

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong if we have no idea about data, tables structures...

Comment: I'm just more looking for help with obvious syntax issues.. this is T SQL I think.

Comment: No, there are no obvious syntax issues, or any syntax issues since you can execute your query. But we can't tell why it returns nothing since we don't know your data, maybe you can share a sample.

Comment: Especially for tables v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE  and v_R_system.

Comment: Either your tables are empty of your WHERE clauses are eliminating all of the results (or some combination).  To check, eliminate the WHERE..AND conditions one by one until you get some results.  Once you get some results, then the last clause you removed was the problem.  If you remove the whole WHERE clause and still no results, then your tables have no data.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this as an SCCM database query.

Consider this query `SELECT * FROM v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE`

That table is empty for me. So is `v_HS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE`. I don't know why these are in the database, but I'd suggest using `v_Add_Remove_Programs` and changing `ProductName0` to `DisplayName0`.

Also, your last to clauses in your `WHERE` statement:

```
and gis1.InstallSource0 like '%standard%'
and gis1.InstallSource0 like '%Enterprise%'
```

How will these both be true? Consider this instead, HOWEVER (see below):

```
and (gis1.InstallSource0 like '%standard%'
OR gis1.InstallSource0 like '%Enterprise%')
```

HOWEVER, these columns are NOT on this table. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to tell whether it's a standard of enterprise version of SQL.